# name validation ruby on rails one field, verify 1st & last name

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like my validation to check and see if a user put two names into the name field when registering for an account on my app. the reason I need this is because I am using Stripe which checks for a "first name, last name". However my registration form only has a "name" field. I want to validate there is a first name and last name in only one field.. can this be done?

my user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  validates :name, presence: true

  has_many :listings, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :sales, class_name: "Order", foreign_key: "seller_id"
  has_many :purchases, class_name: "Order", foreign_key: "buyer_id"
end
```

and my registration form:

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, :autofocus => true, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.email_field :email, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.password_field :password, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

Comment: Any reason you're not using a migration to remove `:name` and add `:first_name` & `:last_name`?

Comment: its a style preference ---is there not a way to validate there is two names in a single field?

Comment: It's possible... but it would be complicated (see answer from odaata). I'd go the route of migrating as mentioned previously, and then use virtual attributes to maintain your stylistic preferences. Railscasts has a great video on virtual attributes: http://railscasts.com/episodes/16-virtual-attributes?autoplay=true

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a regex to test for that using `format` with `validates`, so add something like

```
    validates :name, format: /\w+, \w+/
  #valdiates that a user enters a first and last name when registering to prevent stripe auth errors
```

to your model. Though, you'll probably want a more specific regex for your uses.

See the docs here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#format

Comment: I am not seeing a specific validation for two names...can you point me a little closer....

Comment: I don't think there is a specific validation for two names, but the regex I gave as an example guarantees that the name field contains two 'words' (i.e. strings of characters that are normally found in 'words', denoted by \w) that must be separated by a comma and a space to be valid, otherwise Rails will throw a validation error. This will not allow any model to be saved unless that field has two separate names in it.

Comment: Okay awesome, I will give this a try shortly !! Thank you :-)

Comment: What would happen if a person with the last name of `Van Dyke` enters in their name? I suppose you could format it to allow hyphens, but are you really going to subject your users to having to know that... Nice regex above btw, odaata, not my cup of tea.

Comment: when I use this regrex in my controller I get the following error: The provided regular expression is using multiline anchors (^ or $), which may present a security risk. Did you mean to use \A and \z, or forgot to add the :multiline => true option?

Comment: Ah OK, I thought the anchors would speed it up, but since it's a single field, you don't need them, so try /\w+, \w+/. And @kjmagic13 makes a good point - this will not allow multiple spaces in the names. Thus, people usually recommend two fields for this - it also makes sorting by last name much easier

Comment: sorry - did not get a notification of this response. I will give this a try tonight!

Comment: this worked, thank you and I will consider changed the name field from 1 to  2 fields